# How to get today's date in a particular format in PHP?

Tags: php, echo

What should I do, if I want to `echo` today's date from IST timezone? I want the date to be in a particular simple format, like ex. **10th Jul. 2021** / **7th Sep. 2021**, etc. Is it possible? TBH I am a beginner in this field, so I am still learning stuff...

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Update** : I have solved my own question -

I built this code :

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
echo date('jS F\, Y');
?>
```

And it worked out perfectly. I get my desired result - **10th July, 2021**